# How to reverse vertical bar chart dirction?

Tags: html, css, charts, positioning, bar-chart

I have a very simple vertical bar chart made solely by css:
it is made of list items:

```
<ul class="graph">
<li style="height:50%; ">25</li>
<li style="height:80%;">40</li>
<li style="height:20%;">10</li>
<li style="height:40%;">20</li>
<li style="height:10%;">5</li>
</ul>
```

with the help of css:

```
.graph {
    width:100%;
    height:250px; 
    position:relative; 
    background-color:gray;
}
.graph li{
    bottom:0; 
    width:5%; 
    text-align:center;  
    background-color:#9FC; 
    list-style:none; 
    position:relative;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:1px;  
    display:inline-block;}
```

the problem is that the bars are upside-down. How could I make them right way up?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your **li** elements should be positioned absolute. However you need to set margin for each element. I used it by adding **left** property:

```
<ul class="graph">
<li style="height:50%; ">25</li>
<li style="height:80%;left:20%">40</li>
<li style="height:20%;left:40%">10</li>
<li style="height:40%;left:60%">20</li>
<li style="height:10%;left:80%">5</li>
</ul>
```

And in CSS i modified this:

```
.graph li {
     position:absolute;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3k7Qm/)**